# R Colour scatterplot by third dimension with heatmap

Tags: r, plot

How do you plot a scatterplot colouring the points by a third dimension, where the colour is a heatmap, or shaded graduation of a colour (including a legend would also be nice, but not essential).

The following example shows with a rainbow colour, but I would like to colour shades of blue (or red, green etc.) with light being low values and dark being high values.

```
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
z <- rnorm(10)
colors <- rev(rainbow(101))
zcolor <- colors[(z - min(z))/diff(range(z))*100 + 1]
plot(x,y,col=zcolor,pch=19,cex=1.5)
```

I would like to use the standard plot function if possible rather than swapping to one of the other options.

Comment: Have you checked `colors <- colorRampPalette(c("#132B43", "#56B1F7"), space = "Lab")(101)`? PS: I think it would be easiest to swap to `ggplot` - all comes out of the box, including a gradient legend.

Comment: Have you try to combine your own colorRampPalette ?                        `Example <- colorRampPalette(c('yellow','orange','red'))`

Comment: Thanks, colorRampPalette worked great. @LukeA I realise that plot isn't working too well with a number of things, but I've a presentation due tomorrow and redoing all my plots using an unfamiliar package is not an option. I'll learn about other options when I'm not so time pressed.